# Passing a default value in POST array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I have an MCQ test question page . The question and option are printing by foreach loop and are stored in JSON format. When user submit the for I have a POST array in which i am storing Radio button clicked for a particular question. I have all of it working but there is one bug in it i.e if a user leave  any question the post array get disturb with some unkown index/value value. ANd  the correct answer array have all the the index in it. So i am not able to compare both arrays. How can i place 0 as a value  in array if there is no index/key for that.

HTML FORN

```
 <form id="gi" method="post" name="mockForm" action="checkAnswer.php">

      <?php
      foreach ($json_data as $key => $value) {
          echo
          "<p><span class='que'> Question</span>&nbsp;&nbsp". $value['number']."&nbsp;&nbsp". "<br><hr class='line'>". $value['question']."<br><br>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio'  name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op1' required>" ." " , $value['op1']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op2' required>" ." " , $value['op2']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op3' required>"." "  , $value['op3']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op4' required>"." " , $value['op4']."</pre>"

              "</p>";
      }
      ?>
            <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="SUBMIT">
            <button onclick="hit(); handleClick();">click</button>
       </form>
```

PHP CHECKANSWER.php

```
<?php
$contentOfJsonFile = file_get_contents("example_10.json");
$JsonData = json_decode($contentOfJsonFile, true);

$correctAnswerArray = [];

$wrongCount = 0;
$correctCount = 0;
foreach ($JsonData as $key => $value) {
    array_push($correctAnswerArray, $value['correct_answer']);
}

    $userAnswerArray = $_POST;

$breakForeach = count($userAnswerArray) - 1;
$loopRun = 0;
foreach ($userAnswerArray as $key => $answer) {


    $questionNumber = substr($key, -1);

    if ($correctAnswerArray[$questionNumber] === $answer) {
        # increment correct
        $correctCount++;
    } else if($correctAnswerArray[$questionNumber] === 0) {
        # increment wrong
        $wrongCount++;
    }
    else {
        $wrongCount++;
    }


$loopRun++;

    if($breakForeach == $loopRun ) break;
}
echo "<br>".$correctCount."<br>";
echo $wrongCount;

?>
```

Comment: The obvious solution is to set one of the radio buttons to selected.  If it is an optional question, check on the backend with isset.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh... Please try and learn something from this.

```
<form id="gi" method="post" action="checkAnswer.php">
  <?php foreach ($json_data as $value): ?>
    <p>
        <span class="que">Question</span>
        <?php echo $value["number"]; ?>
    </p>

    <hr class="line">

    <?php 
        for ($i = 1, $i <= 4; $i++) {
            echo sprintf('<input type="radio" name="question[%d] value="%s" required> %s', 
                $value["number"], 
                $value["op{$i}"], 
                $value["op{$i}"]);
        }
    ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
<?php
// FIXME Database
$answerKey = json_decode(file_get_contents("example_10.json"), true);

$score = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $i => $answer) {
    if (isset($answerKey[$i]) && $answerKey[$i] == $answer) {
        // increment correct
        $score++;
    }
}

echo "<br>{$score}<br>";
echo count($answerKey) - $score;
```

Comment: Actually test also contains negative markings scheme so the user will prefer to leave the question. I dont user to click another button to leave question as it will cost there time.

Comment: The post array i am getting is ------
Array ( [question] => Array ( [0] => on [1] => on [2] => on [3] => on [4] => on ) [btnsubmit] => SUBMIT )

Comment: I am not sure what is in your json structures.  I really just refactored this down into something readable.  Checkout the html generated and see where the error is. Stackoverflow cannot solve all of lifes' problems.